# For each loop keeps stopping on second cycle VB

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, foreach

The software I'm writing is being run in a service installed on a computer.
I want to read a text file, process it, and code it to a different path.

the software is doing exactly what it's supposed to do but it only processes 2 files and it stops. I believe that its something to do with the for each loop. I found some information online saying that its to do with the amount of memory being allocated to each cycle of the for each loop.

Any help is appreciated.

my code goes like this.

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\Commsin\", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "ORDER-*.TXT")
      
            Dim filenum As Integer
            filenum = FreeFile()
            FileOpen(filenum, foundFile, OpenMode.Input)
            While Not EOF(filenum)

                <do a bunch of stuff> 
  
            End While

                <more code>

            Dim arrayFileName() As String = GetFileName.Split("\")
            Dim FileName As String = arrayFileName(2)

            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(foundFile, "C:\Commsin\Done\" & FileName)
            
            If IO.File.Exists("C:\Commsin\Done\" & FileName) Then
                My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(foundFile, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin)
                
                NoOfOrders -= NoOfOrders
            End If

Next
```

Comment: [vba] tag removed. VBA and VB.NET are *completely* different languages. Except for superficial similarities in in the syntax they have nothing in common.

Comment: You believe it's the loop? Have you tried debugging the application? If there's at a minimum some sort of error message, it would be beneficial in finding a solution.

Comment: I got this error "Index was outside the bounds of the array." in event viewer. then since its a service that loops this every 5 minutes i get this message then "The process cannot access the file 'C:\Commsin\ORDER-1009.TXT' because it is being used by another process."

Comment: For the second message, you should always wrap file modification operations in a try-catch, because they may fail due to access by other processes which cannot be detected in real time (or even if they can, there's still a race window between detection and trying to perform the operation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, everyone, for your suggestions, I have successfully implemented the recommended changes. It turned out that the issue wasn't with the code itself.

It was with one of the files I was using it had a text row that once split into an array it wasn't at a required length giving an error "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

It was a mistake on the file, I also added some check to prevent this error in the future.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamental mistake: Don't modify the collection you are iterating over, i.e. avoid this pattern (pseudocode):

```
For Each thing In BunchOfThings:
   SomeOperation()
   BunchOfThings.Delete(thing)
Next thing
```

It's better to follow this pattern here (pseudocode again):

```
While Not BunchOfThings.IsEmpty()
   thing = BunchOfThings.nextThing()
   SomeOperation()
   BunchOfThings.Delete(thing)
End While
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to convert your code from the first approach to the second.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to extract the filename from the full path using Split().

Why not just use:

```
Dim fileName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(foundFile)
```

Instead of:

```
Dim arrayFileName() As String = GetFileName.Split("\")
Dim FileName As String = arrayFileName(2)
```